# Javascript debugger similar to Visual Studios debugger?

Tags: javascript, debugging

Is there any debugger like there is in Visual Studio,for example in C#, I can follow every step of the program and find out how the code works, which function does it call first or what value does a certain integer has after loop? Thanks

Comment: Chrome Dev tools? https://developer.chrome.com/devtools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is. It's in Visual Studio!

When you launch a your web application from Visual Studio in Internet Explorer you can set breakpoints in your JavaScript code and use the debugger from Visual Studio just as you would with C#.

Make sure that you have debugging scripts enabled in Internet Explorer.

You can find more info here in the documentation [Client-Side Script Debugging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7seh8d72.aspx) at MSDN.